# jQuery append an img to every div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a thumbnail image with every `thumb` class, but currently I am getting the output below where the images are looping inside the `href` instead. The order of `div`, `href` and `img` must not change. It looks something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junshoo/4dd17hrj/) but this isn't fully working of course...

currently getting:

```
<div class ='thumb'>
  <a href="#" rel="1">
    <img src="">
  </a>
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

required output:

```
<div class ='thumb'>
  <a href="#" rel="1">
    <img src=>
  </a>
</div>

<div class ='thumb'>
  <a href="#" rel="1">
    <img src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

my loop:

```
var thumbnails = [];

$.each(data.productVariantImages,function(key, val){ 
    thumbnails.push(val.imagePath);
});

for(var thumb in thumbnails) {
    $('.thumb').append($('<img>').attr({
        "src":[thumbnails[thumb]]
    }));
}
```

am i looping it wrongly?

edit:

The thumbnails are part of a dynamic gallery where basically every time a user choose a different option in a dropdown list, the sources for the thumbs are supposed to change accordingly.

current html:

```
<div class="thumbnail"><?php 
  foreach($skuDetails['productVariantImages'] as $variantImage){
  if(isset($variantImage) && $variantImage['visible']){
 ?>
<div class="thumb">
  <a href="#" rel="1">
     <img src="<?php echo $variantImage['imagePath']; ?>" id="thumb_<?php echo $variantImage['id']; ?>" alt="" />
   </a> 
</div> <?php }}?>
</div>
```

sample array of thumbnails:

```
["http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png",
 "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png"]
```

sample output:

```
<div class="thumbnail">                     
    <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#" rel="1">
     <img src="http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples.png" id="thumb_323" alt="">
    </a> 
    </div>      

   <div class="thumb">
    <a href="#" rel="1">
     <img src="http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples.png" id="thumb_323" alt="">
    </a> 
    </div>                     
</div>
```

Comment: image tag is a self closing tag  <img><img/> is wrong use  <img src="" />

Comment: basically you want to generate this structure HTML structure for the total number of thumbnails array? Each having one image?

Comment: @Moax6629 yea each thumb class should only have one img src. the total num of array is unknown

Comment: ok and you don't have html structure prior to JS? you want it all done through JS ?

Comment: @zana, It's unclear how exactly the data in your `thumbnails` array relates to the elements with `.thumb` class. Show your `thumbnails` array and explain how exactly you want them to match each other (based on their index?)

Comment: @Moax6629 it's supposed to change dynamically thru dropdown every time user changes option, the thumbnails r supposed to change

Comment: @haim770 ok let me try to update the qns with more details regarding the array

Comment: @zana, Also, if you want it "to change dynamically" you better add it to the question as well (with all the relevant details).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use .each function on .thumb. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.thumb').each(function(){
       $(this).append($('<img>').attr({"src":[thumbnails[thumb]],}));
   });
});
```

Comment: There's no need for `each()`. `$('.thumb').append(...)` will do

Comment: @haim770 but that will append all images to only one div. isn't it?

Comment: No. See http://jsfiddle.net/tf42y91y/. Also, you have some syntax errors (extra `,` and redundant `[]`).

Comment: @Moax6629 it seems like it is still appending to one div

Comment: @Moax6629 your code will append to .thumb div but it should append inside the `a` tag

Answer (score 1):

your loop is focused on wrong element. You append img tag to the thumb class. So, the img tags inside the same  element. You should create div has thumb class inside the loop, and append it to the thumbnail div. That must like

```
var div = $(".thumbnail");

$.each(imageArray, function(index, value){
    var elem = "<div class='thumb'><a href='#' rel='1'></div>";
    div.append($elem);
    $('.thumb').append("<img />").attr("src", value);
});
```

It may be wrong but you should watch the thumbnail element. I cannot write the code to test. But I think the logic must be like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that exact structure, I made a demo using plain JavaScript. Enter a number and the `thumbClone()` function will generate that many. You could probably adapt this function with your existing code easily. I'm in rush, it probably needs refactoring, sorry. :-\

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/pcnh80a9/)

```
function thumbClone(qty) {
  var main = document.getElementById('main');
  var aFig = document.createElement('figure');
  var aLnk = document.createElement('a');
  var aImg = document.createElement('img');

  aLnk.appendChild(aImg);
  aImg.src = "http://placehold.it/84x84/000/fff.png&text=THUMB"
  aFig.appendChild(aLnk);
  aLnk.setAttribute('rel', '1');
  main.appendChild(aFig);
  aFig.className = "thumb";

  console.log('qty: ' + qty);
  var thumb = document.querySelector('.thumb');
  for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    var clone = thumb.cloneNode(true);
    thumb.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

Comment: your structure looks exactly like what i need, thanks i will try to implement this and see how it works

Comment: If you have an array, you can use `var qty = array.length` or something to that effect. You can also add an extra parameter for the url like this maybe: `var url = "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples.png"`

Comment: okay sure i see, but i cant try now yet, will attempt this tmr morning, thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any further assistance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use each loop which will get each class rather than getting only one class below is syntax of each loop

```
$(selector).each(function(){
       // do your stuff here
)};
```

in your case

```
$('.thumb a').each(function(){
       // do your stuff here
        $(this).append($('<img />').attr('src',[thumbnails[thumb]]);
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create the entire div structure for each image.

Lets create the below structure dynamically using the max length of the image array and add the image src .

```
var thumbDivStart = "<div class ='thumb'><a href="#" rel="1">";
var thumbDivEnd = "</a></div>";
var thumbDiv = "";
for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) { 
    thumbDiv = thumbDivStart + "<img src="+imageArray[i]+"/>"+
               thumbDivEnd;
 //Here you can append the thumbDiv to the parent element wherever you need to add it.
}
```